# How do I find common values in a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have two tables - account and account_bal.

1. Each account can have multiple order id associated  to it.
2. Each order have balance associated to it in account_bal table.

I am using below sql query and trying to get the desired output but it is happening somehow. How can I obtain order_id and customer id which have common balance ONLY. Could you please help me to get the correct output. Thanks.

select balance,order_id,account from account a ,account_bal b
where a.order_id=b.order_id
group by balance,order_id,account;

| account_id | Order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 923457586 | 3456 |
| 923457586 | 5678 |
| 923457586 | 2340 |
| 923457586 | 3456 |
| 923457587 | 5670 |
| 923457587 | 4354 |
| 923457587 | 7867 |
| 923457587 | 3400 |

| Order_id | balance |
| --- | --- |
| 3456 | 43 |
| 5678 | 23 |
| 2340 | 23 |
| 3456 | 11 |
| 5670 | 78 |
| 4354 | 90 |
| 7867 | 10 |
| 3400 | 10 |

Output:

| account_id | Order_id | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 923457586 | 5678 | 23 |
| 923457586 | 2340 | 23 |
| 923457587 | 7867 | 10 |
| 923457587 | 3400 | 10 |

Comment: why are there a double 3456 for 923457586 inn the account table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want multiple rows within each group, you want to use analytic functions (and not aggregation). You also need to remove duplicates from `account`:

```sql
SELECT account_id,
       order_id,
       balance
FROM   (
  SELECT a.account_id,
         a.order_id,
         b.balance,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY a.account_id, b.balance) AS cnt
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM account) a
         INNER JOIN account_bal b
         ON a.order_id=b.order_id
)
WHERE  cnt > 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE account (account_id, Order_id) AS
SELECT 923457586, 3456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457586, 5678 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457586, 2340 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457586, 3456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457587, 5670 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457587, 4354 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457587, 7867 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923457587, 3400 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE account_bal (Order_id, balance) AS
SELECT 3456, 43 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5678, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2340, 23 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3456, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5670, 78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4354, 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7867, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3400, 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ACCOUNT_ID | ORDER_ID | BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 923457586 | 5678 | 23 |
| 923457586 | 2340 | 23 |
| 923457587 | 3400 | 10 |
| 923457587 | 7867 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zkPQJRvo)

Comment: as order id 3456 is double in accounts and balance, you would get the wronf result

Comment: @nbk Yes, I'd spotted that and added `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an other way to do it using `group by` and `having` clause :

First we identify balance that is common in more than one account and order :

```
select balance
from account_bal
group by balance
having count(*) > 1
```

Then apply `inner join` by balance to get the expected output :

```
select distinct a.*, ab.balance
from account a 
inner join account_bal ab on ab.order_id = a.order_id
inner join (
  select balance
  from account_bal
  group by balance
  having count(*) > 1
) s on s.balance = ab.balance
```